# How to create directory on remote server using Maven

Tags: maven

I use maven for copy files to remote servers but if the folder doesn't exist the command fails. Any help?

Comment: Share some code with us please :) ?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the [sshexec-maven-plugin](http://evgeny-goldin.com/wiki/Sshexec-maven-plugin) which does what you like.  But this sounds like you are on the wrong road, cause Maven is a built tool not a deployment tool. For those purposes i would suggest puppet or chef etc.